# why is it giving error stackoverflow back?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

so i have been learning c++ for the past few days and now i have a task to make a Recursion and recursive function. i tried to solve it but it always gives this error back (Unhandled exception at 0x00535379 in cours.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00392FC4).)
or sometimes it gives the value of 1 of sum
any ideas for why?

```
int factorialNumber(int a,int b)
{
    int sum;
    if (b==a)
    {
        return b;
    }
        sum = a*b;
        return sum  + factorialNumber(b + 1,a);
}

void main(int sum)
{
    int a=8,b=1;
    factorialNumber(a,b);
    cout <<a <<b<<endl<<sum;
    system("pause>0");
}
```

Comment: `void main(int sum)` ... where did you find this? That's not a valid signature for `main`

Comment: That's the wrong signature for your `main` function, but that's not the cause of your error.

Comment: Your factorialNumber method never ends and keeps calling itself. You are switching between the arguments a and b at every call.

Comment: In addition to the other issues: you don't assign the result of `factorialNumber` to any variable. Maybe you meant: `int sum = factorialNumber(a,b);` ? (and of course remove sum from the parameters of `main`).

Comment: What is the mathematical function you are trying to calculate ? `factorial` means multiplying 1*2* ... *n. This is not what your function is doing despite the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few other error in you code from C++ perspective, like invalid syntax for main, missing header, etc. But ignoring them for now to concentrate on factorial thing. You main error order of passing `a` and `b` to `factorialNumber`. Correcting it like below will work.

```
int factorialNumber(int a,int b)
{
    int sum;
    if (b==a)
    {
        return b;
    }
        sum = a*b;
        return sum  + factorialNumber(a,b + 1);
}
```

Comment: You're correct.  But the first - and most important thing - is to encourage the OP to use his debugger.  If he stepped through the code, he'd quickly notice that parameters a and b weren't incrementing as he expected.  Learning to "debug" is an essential a skill...

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you are not assigning the value of the factorial method to sum in the main method. FYI, the method signature is wrong as you used void.
2. in the factorial method, you are interchanging the variable during calling the recursive function that leads to an infinity loop.